# What is difference between XmlSchemaType/XmlQualifiedName classes

Tags: wcf

Can someone tell me the difference between **XmlSchemaType** and **XmlQualifiedName** class. I'm bit confused when to choose which class. Actually I'm using **IXmlSerializable** interface for my class and to specify schema for this I used **XmlSchemaProviderAttribute** and specify the function which can return either **XmlSchemaType** or **XmlQualifiedName**. Both work fine and I successfully generate the proxy. but unable to find a consolidated analysis which one is to use in which condition.

As per Microsoft

**XmlSchemaType Class**:
The base class for all simple types and complex types.

**XmlQualifiedName  Class**:
Represents an XML qualified name.

but I'm unable to understand the exact difference between these two.

Answer (score 0):

After doing google and reading some article I've finally find the difference between these 2 and understand where to choose what?

There are 3 different types that can implement **IXmlSerializable Interface**

- Content types
- Element types
- Legacy DataSet types

For content types we need to use XmlQualifiedName Class as return parameter (Method name specify in XmlSchemaProvider) and this will require that main root element of XSD will be the complextype.

For elements types we need to use XmlSchemaType Class. Here you can specify any root element in XSD.

For Legacy DataSet types we don't use XmlSchemaProvider attribute. Instead, they rely on GetSchema method for Schema generation.

I've found all this useful information from following MSDN link. A must read article for better understanding how Xml Serialization works in WCF.

[Using the XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx)